# Getting data from OpenWeatherApI using Dart language with TCP/IP protocol

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Hi I am trying to connect using TCP/IP Protocol, I need help checking the Dart code if it is using the right TCP/IP Protocol or not
Github link: https://github.com/fadel1411/open_weather_app_tcp_ip